# MAX-SAT pseudo-boolean optimization(PBO) weighted boolean optimization(WBO) solver

Tags: software

I have come across (state of the art) softwares on MAX-SAT PBO or WBO: examples are WBO, open-WBO, SAT4J, scip. They all seem to work in a way that only command line instruction is involved. I want to construct a C++ programme that involves solving some PBO system (equivalently MAX-SAT or WBO) then do a huge bunch of other things. Just like how cplex or Gurobi. What is the state of art solvers for this process? Thank you.

Comment: [crossposted](https://www.or-exchange.org/questions/10586/max-sat-pseudo-boolean-optimizationpbo-weighted-boolean-optimizationwbo-solver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert of PBO or WBO (I do mixed-integer programming instead). The best information I could find on solvers was the [Pseudo-Boolean Competition 2012](http://www.cril.univ-artois.fr/PB12/) (I could not find a later version), which should give you some idea of the solvers out there. SCIP has an API, and is written in C, so you should be able to the SCIP API for solving problems within source code. If not, it is open source, so at worst, you could write an API yourself and contribute it upstream.